# auto role upon joining/leaving a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

i have setup an auto role that gives a member a specific role whenever they join a specific voice channel, and then removes it when they leave the vc.
but for some reason, the bot is removing the role randomly, seems to happen whenever they mute/unmute. anyone able to help?

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    ship=0
    for i in range(5):
        target_ship=bot.fleets[0][ship]
        if member in bot.get_channel(target_ship).members:
            await member.add_roles(bot.fleet1)
            def check(member,before,after):
                return before.channel!=after.channel
            await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update',check=check)
            await member.remove_roles(bot.fleet1)
        ship+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a voice_state_update occurs when (and is not limited to):

- A member joins a voice channel.
- A member leaves a voice channel.
- A member is muted or deafened by their own accord.
- A member is muted or deafened by a guild administrator.
  (discord.py docs)

Hence, in the line `await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update',check=check)`, when the person is unmuted/muted, the voice state changes, and hence it stops waiting, causing the role to be removed in the lines of code below it.

To fix this, you can:

- Add a role when the member joins the voice channel and the voice state is updated (so the function runs)
- Remove the role when the member leaves the voice channel, when the function will also run.
  Effectively:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    if after.channel == yourvoicechannel and before.channel != yourvoicechannel:
        # user has joined the voice channel, add the role
    elif before.channel == yourvoicechannel and after.channel != yourvoicechannel.id:
        # user has left the voice channel, remove the role
```